# Tableau: Selecting one filter value will automatically select another filter value

Tags: tableau-api

I have a situation where i have two measures (Disease, Coverage). Disease has 4 values and coverage has 3. When I select Disease 1 it always has a coverage type of 3. When I select Disease 2 or 3 it always has a coverage type of 2. When I select Disease 4 it always has a coverage type of 1.

How can I set it up so that users just pick the disease and the coverage type for that disease is automatically selected.

I was hoping this would work...but it didn't

Case [Disease]
when "Disease 1" THEN [Disease] = 1 and [Coverage Type] = 3
END

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you trying to assign an Existing Measure? i.e. Are both Disease and Coverage in the source data you are using? That might not work, you need to use calculated fields.

Comment: Yeah, both variables are in the same dataset. I want the selected value of one to determine the selected value of the other. That way I only have to show the user 1 filter.

Comment: Are the Disease and the Coverage part of the same row? If yes then you can use both of them as "filters" then "show filters" then on the filters "show relevant values" as pointed out. If they are not a part of the same row in your data then you can try to join the data based on your criteria at datasource.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that the two measures are given as is from the data set.
If not, here's a way to create the column `[Coverage]` from `[Disease]`.

Create a new calculated field as follows

```
CASE [Disease]
WHEN '1' then '3'
WHEN '2' then '2'
WHEN '3' then '2'
WHEN '4' then '1'
END
```

and save it as `[Coverage]`

This will give you the `[Coverage]` column.

Bring `[Disease]` and `[Coverage]` to the worksheet and when you select any of the disease, it should correspond to the right `[Coverage]`

Comment: Well, that would recode disease but it doesn't help me to select the values of both filters. Like I said, I want to have a single filter and when you select the value of that filter it will automatically apply the other filter.

Comment: hey man, u wanna try to make both filter appear for `disease` and `coverage`, and in the filter option, select "Only relevant values" for both.

Comment: I don't need both filters to appear because if I pick one the value of the other is known. However, currently, I need to physically set the value of both manually. Ideally, I would just show disease and depending on the disease you select it would automatically select the appropriate coverage filter.